# Best approach for loading Kentico 10 web nodes including caching and permission checking

Tags: kentico

I have a custom product type that gets displayed in a custom listing web part.  I was trying to cache the items for performance reasons, but it's also important to check user permissions as not all products are visible to all users.

```
private static IList<TreeNode> GetUniqueProducts(string clientId, string path)
{
      var pages = CacheHelper.Cache(cs => GetProducts(cs, path), new CacheSettings(10, "cus|" + clientId));
      return GetUniqueProductNamesItems(pages);
}

private static IList<TreeNode> GetProducts(CacheSettings cacheSettings, string rootPath)
{
    var pages = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Types("CUS.Product")
                .Path(rootPath, PathTypeEnum.Children)
                .Published().CheckPermissions().ToList();

    if (cacheSettings.Cached)
    {
          cacheSettings.CacheDependency = CacheHelper.GetCacheDependency("nodes|custom|cus.product|all");
    }

    return pages;
}
```

However I realise that this is caching the first user's list of products.  When in fact I want to store the full list of products in cache - but then check permissions before they get displayed.

The only way of checking permission seems to be as part of a DocumentQuery as per above - but I don't know how to apply that to a cached list of products - or on an individual node.

So is there a good way to achieve what I want?  Without having to loop through each node and individually check user is authorised to access the node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the caching part in your code and I am not quire sure about your cache dependencies.

```
    var pages = CacheHelper.Cache(cs  =>
    {
        var result = CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Types("CUS.Product").Path(rooPath, CMS.DocumentEngine.PathTypeEnum.Children).Published().ToList();
        if (cs.Cached) { cs.CacheDependency = CacheHelper.GetCacheDependency("cus.product|all"); }
        return result;
    },
    new CacheSettings(CacheHelper.CacheMinutes(CurrentSite.SiteName), "custom_products"));
```

If you checking the user read permissions it means you kinda caching per user. Then your cache should be done per user i.e. cachename should be "custom_products"+ UserID.ToString() or something like this.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can cache the list of products - and then before displaying them easily/efficiently check permissions on them.  I'm trying to avoid caching them per user - as that doesn't seem quite right.  It also doesn't seem quite right that I can't make use of caching if I do need to see a user filtered list of a set of products.  Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I added the part of the code where I do in fact cache to my question - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ended up including a user identifier as part of the cache key - and caching per user.  Although it still seems a bit odd - Kentico pointed out that it would be hitting the database anyway to check permissions even if the products were cached!

Comment: What would be the point of caching a query if it can't be used by anyone else?  I was really hoping there was a way to do this.

Comment: @WhiteleyJ at least as the user navigated throughout the site it would have a cached set of products they had permission to as we often displayed lists of products on various pages. Not ideal though.

Comment: @Jen I actually figured out a solution to this but it's kinda ugly.  I'm running a sql query that basically asks for all the NodeIDs that a user has read access to ( join CMS_ACLItem to View_CMS_Tree_Joined to CMS_Role to CMS_UserRole with the bitwise read flag stuff).  Then I save it in a HashSet<int> and cache it by user.  HashSet is very fast for comparing lists so you can filter out pages by nodeid by comparing it to the list.